# How to capture sessionRequestToken in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, browser-session

I have sessionRequestToken  to be sent as form data inside my application.How do I capture this session token?

> UPDATE

My session request token is inside hidden input element

```
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="sessionRequestToken" value="some value"/>
</body>
```

So,to capture it I used CSS/Jquery post processor which goes as follows:

```
Reference Name: sessionRequestToken
Css/Jquery Expression: input[name='sessionRequestToken']
Attribute:value
Match No:1
Default value:NOT_FOUND
```

But,the debug sampler always shows the value of sessionRequestToken as NOT_FOUND.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I selected-->Apply To:Main Sample only.And it worked.earlier I have selected Jmeter Variable.

Comment: What did you apply to to the main sample - the handler script?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should design your test like:

1. First [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - open login page
2. A [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract dynamic parameters (i.e. your `sessionRequestToken` from the response and save it into a JMeter Variable
3. Second HTTP Request - perform login. This time you need to send the JMeter Variable from step 2 instead of hard-coded (recorded) value

---

Be aware that there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which automatically detects any dynamic parameters and works them around so you won't have to worry about performing correlation manually, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for details.

Comment: I selected-->Apply To:Main Sample only.And it worked.earlier I have selected Jmeter Variable.